# What divides Hydrological Unit Code areas of the same level?

Tags: hydrology, gis

I'm trying to better understand [the Hydrological Unit Code (HUC) system of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrological_code#United_States). I understand the basic hierarchy of it (HUC4, 6, 8, 12) and watersheds/drainage areas. Here's what I want to clarify:

A group of HUC8s can be within a single HUC6, because each HUC8 ultimately drains to the pour point of their parent HUC6. **What separates one HUC8 from another HUC8 downstream of it, both within the same parent Hydrologic Unit?** I suspect the answer isn't the natural drainage area, because *the downstream HUC8 would contain the upstream HUC8 in its natural drainage area* - that's based on me thinking that as you shift the discharge point you're examining further downstream, the drainage area you're examining increases.

The most concise, relevant explanation I've come across is from [the USEPA's EnviroAtlas Data Fact Sheet on the subject](https://enviroatlas.epa.gov/enviroatlas/DataFactSheets/pdf/Supplemental/Watershed.pdf):

> A
>   watershed  is 
>   defined  as  the
>   geographic  a
>   rea  within  the 
>   boundary
>   of   a   drainage   divide.   Watershed   boundaries 
>   follow  the  highest  ridgeline  around  the  stream 
>   drainage 
>   area; 
>   the  bottom 
>   of  the  watershed  or  the  pour  point  is  the
>   lowest point of the land 
>   area 
>   where water flows out of the 
>   watershed.
>   Hydrologic   unit   boundaries   do   not   always 
>   surround    a    complete    watershed    but    may    delineate 
>   truncated portions of a larger watershed
>   —
>   for example, the 
>   mid-stem   of   a   larger
>   stream   or   river   along   with   the 
>   tributaries
>   in  that  area. 
>   Hydrologic  units  are 
>   generally 
>   synonymous   with   watersheds   when   their   boundaries 
>   include  all  the  source  area  contributing  surface  water  to
>   a 
>   single   defined   outlet   point.   This   distinction   between 
>   watersheds and HUCs is important in the context of water 
>   resources   data   analysis   and   water   quality   monitoring, 
>   because  the  area  contributing  to  the  downstream  outlet 
>   point in a single HUC may extend beyond its boundaries in 
>   an  upstream  direction  to  include  a  number  of  other  sub-basin HUCs.

This still does not clarify exactly **what separates one HUCx from another HUCx downstream of it, both within the same parent HUC?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused about your misunderstanding as the answer to your question is in the Wikipedia link you posted:

> Regions receive a two-digit code. The following levels are designated
>   by the addition of another two digits.[8] The hierarchy was designed
>   and the units subdivided so that almost all the subbasins (formerly
>   called cataloging units) are larger than 700 square miles (1,800 km2).
>   Larger closed basins were subdivided until their subunits were less
>   than 700 square miles.[7] The 10-digit watersheds were delineated to
>   be between 40,000 and 250,000 acres in size, and the 12-digit
>   subwatersheds between 10,000 and 40,000 acres.[6] In addition to the
>   hydrologic unit codes, each hydrologic unit was assigned a name
>   corresponding to the unit's principal hydrologic feature or to a
>   cultural or political feature within the unit.[7]

So, once you are outside of the 2 digit regions, HUC boundaries (or dividing/outlet points along a continuous stream) that separate an upstream watershed from one a downstream one (that should incorporate the upstream HUC using the classic definition of a watershed) are set to evenly divide up the larger (or containing) HUC.

Comment: My uncertainty was about how the HUC boundaries are divided up. 'Evenly' is made clear in the Wikipedia page and in your answer - I was wondering if there is something more to it, to give HUCs more meaning as naturally or politically distinct areas.

Comment: I don't believe so, but could be wrong. Since political boundaries don't align with watersheds (and even span one to several at a time) I can't imagine that political boundaries had a driving force on the division....but maybe a minor one? Since if a division included a certain political feature it might be named for that political feature. As for other naturally distinct area (a change in the level 3 ecoregions?), I suppose some could drive the naming certainly, but would probably only affect the division if the impact of their consideration didn't greatly alter the area of resulting HUCS.